# How to identify the key and filter string in nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Dynamic JSON value created and set in session similar to below. Each `TestDataUsedDetail` object has Work object and `Work` Object contains `workId` and `workName`.
If workId include string  `-old-` then requiredWork value should be set as oldWork
If workId does not includes the string   `-old-` then requiredWork should be newWork.
If both are mixed then requiredWork should be All.
I tried the following but it is not working. How to do this effectively?

```js
const workData = {
  "TestData": "NewData",
  "TestDataDetail": {
    "TestData": "OldData",
    "address": {
      "add1": 207,
      "add2": "east Stret"
    },
    "passcode": null
  },
  "TestDataUsedDetail": [{
      "Work": {
        "workId": "work-data-new",
        "workName": "Brand"
      }
    },
    {
      "Work": {
        "workId": "work-old-data",
        "workName": "Work Data Used"
      }
    },
    {
      "Work": {
        "workId": "work-new-progress",
        "workName": null
      }
    },
    {
      "Work": {
        "workId": "work-old-data2",
        "workName": null
      }
    },
    {
      "Work": {
        "workId": "work-old-progress",
        "workName": "Work Data not used"
      }
    },
    {
      "Work": {
        "workId": "work-pending-scheduled",
        "workName": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "WorkInfo": [

  ],
  "Workid": null
}



let workDetails = [];
let work = [];
var workRequired, workNew, oldWork;
workData.TestDataUsedDetail.forEach(detail => {
  workDetails = workData.TestDataUsedDetail;
  for (const key in workDetails) {
    if (workDetails.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var element = workDetails[key];
      if (element.Work.workId.includes('-old-')) {
        workNew = true;
      } else {
        oldWork = true;
      }
    }
  }
});

if (workNew && oldWork) {
  workRequired = "All";
} else if (workNew) workRequired = "New";
else if (oldWork) workRequired = "old";
```

Expected Result:
workRequired = "All"

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to change to `workData.TestDataUsedDetail.forEach`  - I assume that is what you meant, right?

Comment: Confusing what expected results are. Also what do you mean by *"mixed"*?

Comment: Mixed I meant If workId includes --old-- and doesnot contains --old--.

Comment: in the above case, It contains both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
const workData = { "TestData": "NewData", "TestDataDetail": { "TestData": "OldData", "address": { "add1": 207, "add2": "east Stret" }, "passcode": null }, "TestDataUsedDetail": [{ "Work": { "workId": "work-data-new", "workName": "Brand" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-data", "workName": "Work Data Used" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-new-progress", "workName": null } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-data2", "workName": null } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-progress", "workName": "Work Data not used" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-pending-scheduled", "workName": null } } ], "WorkInfo": [ ], "Workid": null }



workData.TestDataUsedDetail.forEach(({Work}) => {
  Work.required = Work.workId.indexOf("-old-") !=-1 ? "oldWork " : "newWork "
  console.log(Work) 
})
console.log(workData)
```

Or this:

```js
const workData = { "TestData": "NewData", "TestDataDetail": { "TestData": "OldData", "address": { "add1": 207, "add2": "east Stret" }, "passcode": null }, "TestDataUsedDetail": [{ "Work": { "workId": "work-data-new", "workName": "Brand" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-data", "workName": "Work Data Used" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-new-progress", "workName": null } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-data2", "workName": null } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-progress", "workName": "Work Data not used" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-pending-scheduled", "workName": null } } ], "WorkInfo": [ ], "Workid": null }

const reducedWork = workData.TestDataUsedDetail.reduce((acc, {Work}) => {
  acc[Work.workId.indexOf("-old-") != -1 ? "old" : "new"]++; 
  return acc;
}, {new: 0,old: 0});


let workRequired;
if (reducedWork.new > 0 && reducedWork.old > 0) workRequired = "all";
else workRequired = reducedWork.new > 0 ? "new" : "old"
console.log(workRequired)
```

Comment: This satisfies partially, instead of setting new key value for each object If the object contains newWork and OldWork then at the end one single variable value should be "All".
If object contains only newWork then variable value should be "NewWork". If it contains only oldwork then value should be "Old".

Comment: How does `mixed` look like if you only have one workId

Comment: Is it possible to check all the required values in the object and set one  single value as All/New/Old?

Comment: Is workRequired a variable outside the object?

Comment: @TamilRoja See second example

Comment: What is `roleId`?

Comment: if only one WorkId is present then it should return that particular value. New/Old based on what workIdcontains

Answer (score 0):

Using the reduce method should provide you with cleaner code. You only need to iterate once.

```js
const workData = { "TestData": "NewData", "TestDataDetail": { "TestData": "OldData", "address": { "add1": 207, "add2": "east Stret" }, "passcode": null }, "TestDataUsedDetail": [{ "Work": { "workId": "work-data-new", "workName": "Brand" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-data", "workName": "Work Data Used" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-new-progress", "workName": null } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-data2", "workName": null } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-old-progress", "workName": "Work Data not used" } }, { "Work": { "workId": "work-pending-scheduled", "workName": null } } ], "WorkInfo": [ ], "Workid": null }


var result = workData.TestDataUsedDetail.reduce((acc, detail) => {
  acc.newWork = acc.newWork || detail.Work.workId.includes('-old-');
  acc.oldWork = acc.oldWork || !detail.Work.workId.includes('-old-');
  return acc;
}, { newWork: false, oldWork: false });

if (result.newWork && result.oldWork) workRequired = "All";
else if (result.newWork) workRequired = "New";
else if (result.oldWork) workRequired = "Old";

console.log(workRequired);
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't totall get your need. you have an array for work details and all items in that array may have different key info. so i think determining the need for new or old work you need to this per each record in that array. but if you don't mind that the answer of your problem is below.

```js
let workData = {
   "TestData":"NewData",
   "TestDataDetail":{
      "TestData":"OldData",
      "address":{
         "add1":207,
         "add2":"east Stret"
      },
      "passcode":null
   },
   "TestDataUsedDetail":[
      {
         "Work":{
            "workId":"work-data-new",
            "workName":"Brand"
         }
      },
      {
         "Work":{
            "workId":"work-old-data",
            "workName":"Work Data Used"
         }
      },
      {
         "Work":{
            "workId":"work-new-progress",
            "workName":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Work":{
            "workId":"work-old-data2",
            "workName":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Work":{
            "workId":"work-old-progress",
            "workName":"Work Data not used"
         }
      },
      {
         "Work":{
            "workId":"work-pending-scheduled",
            "workName":null
         }
      }
   ],
   "WorkInfo":[
      
   ],
   "Workid":null
};

let workDetails = workData.TestDataUsedDetail;
let workRequired = "";
let isOldWork = false;
let isNewWork = false;

workDetails.forEach(detail => {
    if(detail.Work) {
    if(detail.Work.hasOwnProperty("workId")) {
        if(detail.Work.workId.indexOf("-old-") > -1) {
        isOldWork = true;
      } else {
        isNewWork = true;
      }
    }
  }
});

if(isOldWork && isNewWork) {
    workRequired = "All";
} else if(isOldWork && !isNewWork) {
    workRequired = "Old Work";
} else if(!isOldWork && isNewWork) {
    workRequired = "New Work";
}

console.log(workRequired);
```